# How to set chart series color for entire series (all points)

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to loop through the entire series to color all points (bars) in the chart pictured below using VBA. This is what I have so far

```
Sub ChartColors()
    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim cht As Chart
    Dim cats As Variant
    Dim j As Integer

    For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each shp In sld.Shapes
            If shp.Type = msoChart Then
                cats = shp.Chart.Axes(xlCategory).CategoryNames

                For j = LBound(cats) To UBound(cats)
                    With shp.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(j).Format.Fill.ForeColor
                        Select Case cats(j)
                            Case "Apple"
                                .RGB = RGB(192, 0, 0)
                            Case "Banana"
                                .RGB = RGB(0, 112, 192)
                            Case Else
                                .RGB = RGB(0, 176, 80)
                        End Select
                    End With
                Next j
            End If
        Next shp
    Next sld
End Sub
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2zld.png)

Comment: To leverage the features that PowerPoint already has, have you considered creating a chart template with your preferred colors, then applying that template with VBA? The code is much simpler.

Comment: Yes, I have a chart template for other formatting, but I want the colors to change dynamically based on the name of each category / series

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code...

```
Option Explicit

Sub ChartColors()
    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim cht As Chart
    Dim sr As Series
    Dim pt As Point
    Dim cats As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each shp In sld.Shapes
            If shp.Type = msoChart Then
                Set cht = shp.Chart
                With cht
                    For i = 1 To .SeriesCollection.Count
                        Set sr = .SeriesCollection(i)
                        For j = 1 To sr.Points.Count
                            cats = sr.XValues()(j)
                            Select Case cats
                                Case "Apple"
                                    sr.Points(j).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(192, 0, 0)
                                Case "Banana"
                                    sr.Points(j).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 112, 192)
                                Case Else
                                    sr.Points(j).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 176, 80)
                            End Select
                        Next j
                    Next i
                End With
            End If
        Next shp
    Next sld
End Sub
```